# といえばそれまでだ meaning

Tags: grammar

> 若者にありがちな悩みといえばそれまでだが、大人にとっては重大な問題だった。

The context is that the main character has never felt challenged until this point in his life. My guess is that the sentence means something like "although this is a common issue for young people (and that's the end of it), it's a big problem for an adult."

What does といえばそれまでだ mean in this sentence?

Comment: Related/dup? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82839/45489

Comment: Yes the link you provided answers my question.